# C++ reinterpret cast?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I would like to cast one object of the class PointsList to another object Points3DList (and vice versa) where:

```
template <class T>
class PointsList
{
    protected:
            std::vector <Point <T> *> points;  //Only illustration, not possible with templaes
};
```

and

```
 template <class T>
class Points3DList
{
    protected:
            std::vector <Point3D<T> *> points;  //Only illustration, not possible with templaes
};
```

Between Point and Point3D there is no relationship (inheritance nor composition)...

```
template <class T>
class Point
{
    protected:

            T x;
            T y;

    public:
            Point( const T &x_, const T &y_ ) : x ( x_ ), y ( y_ ) {}
            inline T getX() const {return x;}
            inline T getY() const {return y;}
            inline void setX ( const T &x_ ) {x = x_;}
            inline void setY ( const T &y_ ) {y = y_;}
            ....
};

template <class T>
class Point3D
{
    protected:

            T x;
            T y;
            T z;
};
```

What do you think about conversion

```
Points3DList <T> *pl3D = new Points3DList <T> ();
...
PointsList <T> *pl = reinterpret_cast < PointList <T> * > ( pl3D );
```

where pl3D represents pointer to Points3DList object.. Can reinterpret_cast be used in this case or it is better to create a conversion function? Data model in this case can not be changed...

Comment: It's a terrible idea, don't do it. Hard to demonstrate what you should do without the definitions of `Point` and `Point3D`, though. Also, why are you storing pointers to values instead of the values themselves, in the vector?

Comment: That's still not enough information about the `Point` and `Point3D` classes. If I want to convert them, I need to be able to set the values they contain. All you've shown is four classes that only have protected members (how am I to use those directly?).

Comment: I assume `Point` is really `Point2DCartesian`. By the way, members you define inside the class definition are implicitly `inline`, your use of the keyword there is redundant.

Comment: @GMan. It was a mistake, I corrected it...

Comment: It's still a mistake, since you have `Point` with a supposed-constructor `Point2D`; one of those is incorrect. In any case, can I ask again why you're using pointers so much?

Answer (score 6):

The behaviour here will be *completely* undefined.  Don't do it!

Comment: Technically, it's implementation-defined (except for a few simple cases).

Comment: @GMan: Even in the case of non-PODs?  (Such as the OP's classes containing vectors?)

Comment: @Oli: Well, the cast is being done on pointers, who's "mapping is implementation-defined." (§5.2.10/3) That said, I think it's clear the implementation-defined result is "crash".

Comment: The problem is within STL's vector. There is a lack of casting without copying the whole vector. If the size of stored types has same size the cast is possible.  Here is, because the pointers to structures has the same size. The implementation of std::vector <Point <T> *> and std::vector <Point3D <T> *> will probably have identical implementation, but that's implementation defined. So doing a reinterpret cast will probably work, but since it's undefined you should not do one.

Comment: @lionbest: Is there any way how to cast PontsList <-> Points3DList without creating new objects?

Comment: @lan: Without virtual functions and interface it will be not safe.

Comment: @lionbest: Could you give me short example, please?

Comment: It'll be *undefined* as soon as they try to access it.  The *mapping* between pointer to T1 and pointer to T2 is implementation defined.  Accessing an object through a pointer of a different type is *undefined*.

Comment: I think it is too overheat. Just go back to C and change vector to C array. So you could `reinterpret_cast< Point<T> ** > ( new Point3D <T>* [ 10 ] ) `, but remember that Point and Point3D must be POD so parameter T as well (no destructor or constructors!). But remember to not store new Point<T> in Point3D<T> array. It is of course not so safe so use wisely.

Answer (score 1):

You must write your own cast function (constructor or friend function).

Something like:

```
template <class T>
class PointsList
{
    PointsList(Points3DList& p3d) : x(p3d->x), y(p3d->y) {};
...
```

And use:

```
PointsList <T> *pl = new PointList( pl3D );
```

Comment: But reinterpret_cast very dangerous. In this case you need a wrapper.

Comment: @Ian: don’t count on this being slow. Compilers today are *hellishly* smart. I’m working with an equivalent code at the moment that does pretty much what SVGreg has proposed (but don’t use pointers! `new` *is* slow!). Now comes the surprise: **the compiler makes no copy!** It optimizes the copies completely away, and all that remains are integer values that are directly manipulated.

Comment: @Ian: Speed is not your primary concern, it's your last concern. Your primary concern is a working, correct, maintainable program. Note that speed isn't a factor; in fact, if you do those right, speed comes automatically. Never code for speed, code for correctness.

Comment: @Ian: First, what Konrad and GMan have said; Second, premature optimization is the root of all evil (D. Knuth) - worry about slowness **after** finding out that it is **indeed** slow; Third, in case you do find out that it is indeed slow, you'd ought to write your own copy-on-write optimization or something of the sorts (which can be tricky and dangerous).

Comment: use a boost shared pointer in both classes for the vector inside. This way you don't need to copy the vector.

Answer (score 0):

```
PointsList <T> *pl = reinterpret_cast < PointList <T> * > ( pl3D );
```

This doesn't make sense. Terribly Wrong. You'll get only garbage out of such cast!

How do you even expect `reinterpret_cast` to interpret `Point` and `Point3D` to make the casting succeed?